# Insert object into MongoDB subdocument

Tags: node.js, ajax, mongodb, mongoose, insert

I currently have an array which is as follows (this is names arrayOfObjects)

[image]
What I need to do is insert this object into my mongodb database using mongoose. However I cant seem to get the insert to work.

Here is the section of my schema which represents where the data should be entered:

```
positionsApplied:[{
        position_id:String,
        index_position: Number
}],
```

Ajax Call:

```
$.ajax({
                   url: "/insertPositionIndex",
                   type: "POST",
                   dataType: "json",
                   data: {
                      array:array
                   },
                   success: function (data) {
                      console.log(data);

                }
              })
```

and my post request:

```
  app.post('/insertPositionIndex', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body); // This returns the image below

          User.update(
            { "_id": req.user._id},
            {
            "$push":
                {
                 "positionsApplied":{
                   $each: req.body.array
                   }
                }
            }
        ).exec(function (err, result) {
               console.log(result);
               res.send({ results: result });
          });
    });
```

[image]
But When I run this code, and try to log the data returned to the ajax call I get :

```
(node:79068) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): MongoError: The argument to $each in $push must be an array but it was of type NULL
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure `req.body.arrayOfObjects` has correct value ? looks like it is logging as `undefined`

Comment: agree with @Veeram. In your ajax call, you should send data as: `data: {                  key: arrayOfObjects }`. And in your post request, try to print `key` and make sure you are receiving intended data.

Comment: @Veeram when I log the arrayOfObjects in the console the above image is what comes up, so i think the issue is definitely passing it to the post request. When i set the variable key to arrayOfObjects and pass it I still get undefined with the same error message as above, I'm just not familiar with pushing objects to a subdocument .. is there anything else I could be doing wrong? I appreciate the help too btw! :)

Comment: @AnkitGomkale when I log the arrayOfObjects in the console the above image is what comes up, so i think the issue is definitely passing it to the post request. When i set the variable key to arrayOfObjects and pass it I still get undefined with the same error message as above, I'm just not familiar with pushing objects to a subdocument .. is there anything else I could be doing wrong? I appreciate the help too btw! :)

Comment: `$each` needs an array as argument, you provide an object, as the error message says.

Comment: @TGrif is there a way for me to enter the object into the database?

Comment: @user Transform your object to an array of objects.

Comment: @TGrif is my image above not an array of objects though (Sorry I'm a bit new to this stuff)

Comment: Sorry @TGrif, I just transformed my object into an array of objects (I've updated the question) .. I'm still however getting another error (updated in the question)

Comment: No problem @user but comments are not chat otherwise it become soon illisible. Also I think it's not a good idea to update your answer without keeping track of the original question elements. When I say _transform your object_ I mean server side. This time the error message says it's null. So console.log your data until you get what you want for making the db call.